# Can I Mount auxiliary lights for Hero Honda Passion 2002 bike?

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, headlight, hero-honda

I am having a Hero Honda Passion 2002 model bike. The head light is very low and it works on engine power not on the battery, due to this riding bike in no light area with lots of ups and downs are trouble some because until vehicle is not in good speed head lights are not luminous enough.

So what would be the best solution for this problem?

Would mounting an auxiliary lights solve my problem and is it possible to mount auxiliary lights for Hero Honda Passion 2002 model bike?

Comment: Anything is possible. If you decide to get some, I'd suggest you get some LED lights, as they are (or can be) very bright and shouldn't soak up a lot of power. As for why the light on your bike is going dim, I'd wonder if you don't need a new battery. Accessories normally run off of the battery which is in turn recharged by the alternator/generator (I don't know what your bike runs). You may check to see what the voltage at the battery is ... if that is the original battery, you are well over due for a replacement.

Comment: I wonder if installing a capacitor to act as an electrical energy buffer would help here. It should be feasible; just need to size the capacitor (and resistor) appropriately

Comment: It is Older designed wiring system. Headlights are not connected to battery it is directly connected to Engine, and it directly works on Dynamo generated electricity. If you notice this bike is of Year 2002 almost vintage category and it does not even have a self start, But definitely it is fun to ride!

Answer (score 6):

I would not want to increase load to your dynamo.  I'm skeptical that you actually have that type of charging system but can't back my claim.

IF it is a dynamo then I would do something in order to add your accessory lighting load.

***- Replace your current headlight with an LED version, it will consume less electricity and give you room to add the accessory lighting.***

Then, I would add the accessory lighting but add it as LED in order to keep the load low on your dynamo.